# Fat Free framework jquery Ajax post request is not working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, fat-free-framework

I am new to fat free framework and this is my first time I am using it.I am trying to make a ajax post request with jquery in fat free framework as explained in [article](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/wiki/AJAX-Form-Post-example).

I have made a register controller that receives the post data and validates the data and then insert into the database. If error exists then the error is added to an array and if not then success message is returned as json.

```
    public function register()
{
    $f3=Base::instance();
    if($this->f3->exists('POST.register')) {

        $audit = \Audit::instance();
        $user = new User($this->db); 
        $err = array();
        $data = array(); 
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];

        if ($audit->isEmpty($user_email)) {
             $err['user_email'] = 'Email cannot be empty';
        }


        if ($audit->isEmpty($user_name)) {
            $err['user_name'] = 'Username cannot be empty';
        }


        if ($audit->isEmpty($user_pass)) {
            $err['user_pass'] = 'Password cannot be empty';
        }

        if(empty($err)) {
            $crypt = \Bcrypt::instance();
            $user_pass = $crypt->hash($user_pass);
            $security_token = $crypt->hash(mt_rand(1,9999999));
            $this->f3->set('DATA.user_name',$user_name);
            $this->f3->set('DATA.user_email',$user_email);
            $this->f3->set('DATA.user_pass',$user_pass);

            $save = $user->add('DATA');
            if($save) {
                $data['success'] = true;
                $data['message'] = "Registered";
            }
        } 

        else {
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['err']  = $err;
        }  

        $this->f3->set('pageTitle','Register');
        $this->f3->set('bodyClass','register-page');
        $this->f3->set('view','user/register.htm');
        echo json_encode($data);

    }


    else {
        $this->f3->set('pageTitle','Register');
        $this->f3->set('bodyClass','register-page');
        $this->f3->set('view','user/register.htm');

    }

}
```

I have made a simple ajax post request with jquery that sends the data from the registerform. The php code is working perfectly if I request normally without ajax. If the request is made with ajax then the request does not work. What could be the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var form = $('#registerForm');
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var method = form.attr('method');
        var data = form.serialize();
        form.submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type    : method,
                url     : url,
                data    : data,
                dataType  : 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                  if(!data.success) {
                     if (data.err.user_email) {
                        $('#user_name_error').html('<div class="error"> ' + data.err.user_email + ' </div>');
                      }                         
                  }
                  else {
                        $('#registerForm').prepend('<div id="thankyou"> ' + data.message + ' </div>');
                  }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: try to debug what $_POST get i suspect $_POST gets $_POST['data']

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are expecting a JSON object to be returned but in fact you are getting a JSON string.

What I would do is convert the JSON string returned from your server using $.parseJSON and then access it exactly as you are trying to do.

For example your success function will look something like:

```
success: function(data) {
  data = $.parseJSON(data);   // <== Include this line
  if (!data.success) {
    if (data.err.user_email) {
      $('#user_name_error').html('<div class="error"> ' + data.err.user_email + ' </div>');
    }                         
  }
  else {
    $('#registerForm').prepend('<div id="thankyou"> ' + data.message + ' </div>');
}
```